# Apply udev rule on reboot if device is present

Tags: usb, keyboard, udev

This code must be executed each time my Keychron K1 keyboard is about to be used:

`echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`

The code enables Fn keys as the Keychron suggests on Linux.

I put it in a script `/home/me/k1add`

After hours of desperation I successfully wrote this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hid", ENV{HID_PHYS}=="*input0", ACTION=="add",
ATTRS{idVendor}=="05ac", ATTRS{idProduct}=="024f", RUN="/home/me/k1add"
```

(I wrapped the rule text here for your convenient reading).

The rule goes to:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/10-my.rules
```

Now if I unplug and plug back the keyboard the rule applies and I am happy.
But after I restart the PC nothing happens. So what is the way here to make it run on reboot? I know I can add this code to some of the `rc` scripts, but then this code would execute even if I use another keyboard, which might not be a big problem but anyway I believe it's udev's work to run a script each time a device is ready.

I guessed there might be another `ACTION` but `man udev` does not list possible actions. I know I can see actions with `udevadm monitor` but this command can only be executed after the system is fully booted, which is too late to detect the udev action.

Comment: Where did you write that rule to? `/etc/udev/rules.d/`? If so, what is the name of the `.rules` file? 

Comment: @matigo  `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-my.rules`

Comment: Put the script under /usr/local/bin/ and change the path to it in your udev rule

Comment: It may be worthwhile to change the `.rules` file to be prefixed with `99` or another "high" number as there could be some items that need to be handled before the keyboard. The `.rules` files are read in the order they appear in the directory, so items you make are generally best added to the "end" of the directory 